# Getting error mysql_field_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource for export Mysql to Excel

Tags: php, mysqli, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export my MySQL query to MsExcel using PHP script, one execution of script I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: mysql_field_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given php file on line 161

The data is exporting, but headings (field names of the mysql of the table) are not exporting. Also, I expected to have every field on a separate cells, but its saved each row in one cell.

**Here is the PHP Script:**

```
$data = '';
$header = '';

$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli'], $export_sql) or die ("<b>Couldn't execute SQL query:</b> " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['mysqli']));

$fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);

for ($i=0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $header .= mysql_field_name($result, $i). "\t";    // line 161
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    $line = '';
    foreach ($row as $value) {

        if ((!isset ($value)) || ($value == "")) {
            $value = "\t";

        } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"'.$value.'"'."\t";
        }

        $line .= $value;
    }

    $data .= trim($line). "\n";
}

$data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);

if ($data == "") {
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";
}

header ("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export.xls");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";
```

Any suggestions to resolve the problem?

Comment: You're mising mysql and mysqli functions. You can't do that.

Comment: `mysql_field_name()` = `mysql_*` function; as John said.

Comment: *"Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
`mysqli_fetch_field_direct()` [name] or [orgname]
`PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()` [name]"* - As per http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php

Comment: What's `$result`?  I'm assuming it's a MySQLi result.  That means you *can't* use `mysql_field_name`.  That's a MySQL function.  You need to use MySQLi functions, you can't mix-and-match.

Comment: ^--« Exactly. This isn't *gin & tonic* ;-)

Comment: @JohnConde I'm aware that **mysql_field_name()** is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and tried to **mysqli_fetch_field_direct()** instead, but I got `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`